# Split row according to last column values and save them into different files

Tags: matlab

I have a txt file which have 9 column and the last column is either 0 or 1. I want to save them into different txt file based on the value of last column.How do I do this using matlab?

txt file

```
43 34 6 8 2 6 2 3 0

23 54 2 5 8 2 61 6 1

46 4 6 8 23 6 2 3 0

3 5 2 75 48 23 1 6 0

3 54 23 5 58 2 1 6 1

46 4 67 8 3 6 24 23 0

32 5 2 75 98 23 1 6 1
```

Comment: There are a few different things here, which parts are you struggling with? If all of them, start off with a Matlab tutorial and then ask a more specific question if necessary including a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know how to save matrix to files but not the way to split the matrix.

Here I just provide a solution that can help you split the matrix according to the last column:

```
% ending with 0 in each row
m0 = m(find(m(:,end)==0),:);
>> m0
m0 =

   43   34    6    8    2    6    2    3    0
   46    4    6    8   23    6    2    3    0
    3    5    2   75   48   23    1    6    0
   46    4   67    8    3    6   24   23    0

% ending with 1 in each row
m1 = m(find(m(:,end)),:);
>> m1
m1 =

   23   54    2    5    8    2   61    6    1
    3   54   23    5   58    2    1    6    1
   32    5    2   75   98   23    1    6    1
```

then you can save the matrices `m0` and `m1` in different .txt files, e.g., `dlmwrite('m0.txt',m0)` and `dlmwrite('m1.txt',m1)`

**DATA**

```
m = [43 34 6 8 2 6 2 3 0

23 54 2 5 8 2 61 6 1

46 4 6 8 23 6 2 3 0

3 5 2 75 48 23 1 6 0

3 54 23 5 58 2 1 6 1

46 4 67 8 3 6 24 23 0

32 5 2 75 98 23 1 6 1];
```